# Passing null value to a DateTime? parameter get the parameter populated with random values

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

C#
Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate, Asp.net MVC 3 project

I'm passing null to a method expecting a DateTime? parameter
In debugging mode the parameter is populated with a random different value every time

Here is the image:
[image]

Comment: DateTime is a structure. It is not a Class. So its values can never be null

Comment: Did you upgrade this from an older project? Is this a dnx project?  @geo is nullable so it can be null.

Comment: @geo The OP Added ? to DateTime, so it should be nullable

Comment: Try cleaning the solution and rebuild see if this problem still happens

Comment: @RonBeyer the project was upgraded from visual studio 2010 long time ago, it's the first time that I can see this behavior. I don't know what dnx is

Comment: @User2012384 Yep, tried several times, also deleted all the bin and obj folders and rebuild after that, but the problem persist

Comment: What if you remove the "Static" from the ObtenerInformationLotesPenientesNoImed?

Comment: @User2012384 I removed "static" and still not working. Anyway the static modifier should not be there. Now I'm trying to pass a value different of null but I can't see the parameter value in the debugger and the watch window show a CS0103 code error in the fecha parameter

Comment: What version of the framework are you targeting? This may be a RyuJit bug.

Comment: Net Framework 4, searching about RyuJit bug, first time that I heard of it

Comment: http://nickcraver.com/blog/2015/07/27/why-you-should-wait-on-dotnet-46/ sounds very similar.

Comment: I just run the command Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework -Name useLegacyJit -Type DWord -Value 1 as suggested, but still not working

Comment: The same project is working fine when I debug in Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Here is a good article about DNX (a "Dot Net eXecution environment"): [What is DNX?](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/what-is-dnx/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check with the variable like

```
 if(fecha.HasValue)
    {
    //do required
    }
    else
    {
//set a default date time    
fecha=DateTime.MinValue
    }
```

Comment: Thansk for the suggestion, but the problem is that in debugging I get wrong values